# Java Swing - Dynamic List that Fills Available Space?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

This doesn't seem like it should be very hard but I can't figure out how to do this:

I have a subclass of `JPanel`. It has a fixed height, but can be any width. The subclasses, on construction, set their preferred size using `setPreferredSize()`, which means I have to provide a width in addition to the height.

I would like to make a scrolling list of some number of my subclass, where the subclasses all fill the available horizontal space.

Right now I have a scroll view containing a `JPanel` containing my subclasses. The containing `JPanel` uses a `BoxLayout` with a vertical orientation.

Vertically, it looks great. Horizontally, my custom panels are just stuck at the preferred size. What would be the easiest way to make my panels fill the available horizontal space? I tried writing some layout listeners for them, but the performance was flakey (it seems that sometimes the event messages get dropped?) and the code looked hacky. Other views, such as the `JList`, `JTree`, and scroll views seem to resize automatically to fill the available space in a `BoxLayout`, so I feel like there must be something I can do in my `JPanel` subclass that I haven't thought of.

I'm open to using another Layout Manager if something else is better suited for this. I looked at `GridBagLayout`, but that seemed more geared towards static layouts where components aren't added and removed at runtime.

Edit: I found [this on Oracle's Documentation for BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) which has an example that looks exactly like what I want:

> What if none of the components has a maximum width? In this case, if all the components have identical X alignment, then all components are made as wide as their container. If the X alignments are different, then any component with an X alignment of 0.0 (left) or 1.0 (right) will be smaller. All components with an intermediate X alignment (such as center) will be as wide as their container. Here are two examples:
>
> [image: Image Showing What I Want]

Could someone show me the code that will produce the same results? The example code in the documentation doesn't look like it covers this particular picture.

Comment: Instead of setting the preferred size, try overriding `getPreferredSize` so it returns the width of the container you want to fill. Also override min/max since different layout managers are different. IIRC max size is the one BoxLayout likes.

Answer (score 0):

When you put your component in a [`JScrollPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html), your component may implement the [`Scrollable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Scrollable.html) interface to adjust the scrollpane’s behaviour. By doing this you can implement the method [`getScrollableTracksViewportWidth()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Scrollable.html#getScrollableTracksViewportWidth%28%29) to return `true` so your component will always have the available width and be scrollable in vertical direction only.

This is how `JList`, `JTable`, `JTree`, and all the text components of Swing do it.

Comment: I made those suggested changes but it doesn't seem to have changed anything. I have several of my custom components all placed in a standard `JPanel` which, in turn, is placed in a `JScrollPane`... I feel like your suggestions only apply to if you have a single component directly in the `JScrollPane`. Unless I'm mistaken, though, it's not possible to put multiple components directly in a single `JScrollPane`... is it? If it is, I couldn't figure out how.

Comment: You can make a subclass of `JPanel` which implements the `Scrollable` interface. This way you ensure that the `JPanel` will always have the `ScrollPane`’s width. Then you need a layout manager on that panel which distributes the actual width to the children, like `GridLayout`, `GridBagLayout`, and `BorderLayout` do. Unfortunately, `BoxLayout` does not.

Answer (score 0):

Alright - I found the problem. It appears that the default implementation of `getMinimumSize()` and `getMaximumSize()` will simply return the value of `getPreferredSize()` if it is set. So by setting a preferred size without a maximum size, my maximum size was the preferred size. By overriding `getMaximumSize()` to return (99999, preferredHeight), it now works exactly as I want.